# Understanding the Luckin Coffee case

Tags: stocks

I'm reading this announcement: [Luckin Coffee Agrees to Pay $180 Million Penalty to Settle Accounting Fraud Charges](https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2020-319). And I have these questions:

1. Why did the SEC sue Luckin Coffee instead of the investors suing? And no class action from the investors as well, that's weird.
2. If both the investors and the SEC filed a suit against Luckin Coffee, and Luckin Coffee does not have enough money, who would it pay first?
3. How will the SEC use the penalty money? Will it be used to pay the investors?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about personal finance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Investors did sue](https://www.luckincoffeesecuritieslitigation.com/) in a class action.
2. If the company can't pay its obligations in full, who, when, and how much creditors are paid would be determined by bankruptcy proceedings.
3. [According to Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/05/secfines.asp), "If investors or others were harmed financially due to a transgression, the penalties collected will be used to recover those losses and make those investors whole. Until the passage of the Sarbanes-Oxley Act of 2002, all penalties the SEC obtained were paid to the United States Treasury." In the [SEC's press release announcing the $180M fine](https://www.sec.gov/litigation/litreleases/2020/lr24987.htm), the SEC stated, "This payment may be offset by certain payments Luckin makes to its security holders in connection with its provisional liquidation proceeding in the Cayman Islands. The transfer of funds to the security holders will be subject to approval by Chinese authorities."